# Rate constant converion

Tags: kinetics, units

I  need to calculate the half life for a first order reaction for which I need the rate constant $k$. From literature I observed that for a very closely simulated experiment I obtained the numerical value of $k$ but the unit of $k$ was given in $\frac1{\mathrm s}\cdot\frac1{\mathrm{kPa}}$.

I am only familiar with $k$ in $\frac1{\mathrm s}$. from which I can easily estimate the $t_{1/2}$.

Can somebody please explain how I convert the $\frac1{\mathrm s}\cdot\frac1{\mathrm{kPa}}$ unit to $\frac1{\mathrm s}$.

Additional informaton: The laboratory experiment was conducted at approx $85\ \mathrm{kpa}$ and approx $100\ \mathrm{kpa}$ is $1\ \mathrm{atm}$.

Answer (score 1):

First order rate constants are only in  1/time, i.e. the inclusion of pressure does not make any sense if it is first order.

If $X$ is a quantity *proportional to   the concentration* then for a first order reaction $X=X_0e^{-kt}$ where $X_0$ is the amount at time zero. Hence $\ln(X/X_0) = -kt$ from which you can see that the units of $k$ are 1/time.